Plastic washer placement for prefab corrugated roof
I'm putting together a prefab garden shed consisting entirely of sheet metal bracing and corrugated metal roofing. The instructions are extremely sparse. All of the bracing was connected by metal screws without any washers.
Now I'm at the roofing part and the same screws will be used to attach two overlapping corrugated sheets to each other but also a plastic washer should be used, but with no indication where to place the washer. Between the screw and the first (closest to screw head) sheet sort of makes sense I guess, but the washer wouldn't seem to serve its usual purpose there as the screw head is larger than the washer. Perhaps it's to seal against rain?
My wife has the entire inside of shed already planned out and is tapping her fingers waiting for this roof to be installed so the dream can become a reality so any help here is greatly appreciated.
The roofing sheets in question: two identical sheets will be placed side-by-side with 1 "segment" of overlap:

The metal screw & washers in question:


On metal roofing, usually there is a rubber washer under the screw head for sealing.

The washers also serves other purposes: they help prevent the screw head from scratching through the finish on the roofing and siding, they distribute pressure to avoid metal fatigue, and they help avoid electrolytic corrosion. If they were not used elsewhere, I'd remove those sheet-metal screws and add washers.
